# Viber - how to prevent screenshotting and implement checkboxes

Tags: android, ios, viber, viber-bot

I've received a functional requirements document for a Viber bot, that must be able, among other things, to:

1. Prevent the user from screenshotting the chat with the bot. (Both Android and IOS)
2. Show a list with checkboxes to the user. The user can select several options and send them to the server at once.

For the first - I've looked into "Secret Chats" (long tap -> hide), but you can't do it on a bot and, of course, the bot itself cannot force its own chat to be secret automatically.
**Is there any option for the bot to tell the Viber app - "Don't screenshot me"?**

As for the second - I'm completely at a loss. From what I have read, Viber can only send text or buttons. I can think of a workaround - to show a set of options with the corresponding buttons, when the user clicks on a button - remember that selection, and send all the options back to the user with a tick mark next to that option. The second click on the same button removes the tick. But this idea looks like a bad user experience to me and also it's not what the client has in mind.
**Is there any Viber keyboard with checkboxes?**